# Python Image conversion with PIL library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to Python and I have tried sample code I have been given.

I Want to convert bulk TIFF files to JPG. The TIFF size will be 3MB or more. I want to resize to my requirement width is 1200 height also I will provide some Y

When I run sample codes given

For example:

original image size is 1748 X 2479

```
import PIL
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageFile
from exceptions import IOError

img = PIL.Image.open("p3.tif")
img.MAXBLOCK = 2**20
destination = "x.jpeg"
img.resize((1200,1800))

try:
    img.save(destination, "JPEG", quality=10, optimize=True, progressive=True)

except IOError:
    PIL.ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
    img.save(destination, "JPEG", quality=10, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

Its not resize the value what I have given.

Comment: Who is the "you" in your question? What sample codes have you tried? Where did you get them?

Comment: Also, as a side note: 1200x1800 is not 1200-height, it's 1200-width, 1800-height.

Answer (score 3):

As [the docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) say, `resize`

> Returns a resized copy of this image.

So, this line:

```
img.resize((1200,1800))
```

… does not resize an image in-place, it returns a new, resized, image. That's the one you want to save.

So:

```
img1200 = img.resize((1200, 1800))
img1200.save(destination, "JPEG", quality=10, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

Meanwhile, whatever tutorial or sample code you were following, if it gave you this code, you should find a better source.